# Video recording android app only record the blank screen in Samsung Galaxy Nexus and Samsung Tab GT-P3100 (7")

Tags: android

I'm currently developing the video recording android application and try to encounter the problem that I can't fix it. 
My application is successfully running in Samsung Note II and Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.0
however, in Samsung Galaxy Nexus and Samsung Tab GT-P3100 , when  I record only see the blank screen and the device do recording and save video .mp4  in device.
When I playback the video, the message prompt is "Video can't play".

Comment: check out size of video ur playing it may be 0bytes